# ¿Se pueden quitar las carreteras y demás elementos en google maps para que solo se muestren los polígonos que hice?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

[image: Caprura de mapa]

Solo quiero que se visualicen los polígonos, ya que las carreteras y demás elementos hacen que no se aprecie bien el mapa

Comment: Sería ideal que nos muestres el código que tienes para analizarlo.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear tu propio estilo para el mapa, quitando carreteras, lineas para los limites y las etiquetas, incluso dependiendo del nivel de zoom; con el editor de Google https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Cuando le des finish te dará el JSON para usarlo en tu js

```
    var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
    [
      {
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    );
```

Creas tu mapa

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 55.647, lng: 37.581},
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'terrain',
                'styled_map']
      }
    });
```

Y agregas tus estilos

```
    map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
```

[Documentacion de Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cambiar el estilo para apagar o encender tipos de elementos/features.(ver [Hiding Map Features with Styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/hiding-features?hl=es-419))

Dado que tengas creado tu objeto `map`

```
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 13,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.924229,-1.396841),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

En tu caso, para apagar los caminos:

```
map.setOptions({styles: [{
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "featureType": "road",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
}]});
```

Jugando con los valores de `elementType` y `featureType` puedes cambiar visibilidad, colores y opacidad de geometrías, labels, íconos y hasta el agua.

Comment: para quitar mas elemntos se hace un setOption para todos o se puede ocupar el mismo

Comment: y gracias por responder

Comment: Puedes usar el mismo. Si te fijas, `styles` es un arreglo. Dentro de ese arreglo puedes darle estilos a cada `elementType` y `featureType`